# Matlab Matrix multiplication element wise from different sized matrices

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix, multiplication

I am optimizing a MatLab script by using vector multiplication instead of for loops. There, I got a problem with the vector selection.

In my calculation I got two matrices, `M1(x,x,x,x)` and `M2(x,x)`. When I try to vectorize those matrices and multiplicate them elementwise, I get an error. Their sizes mismatch.

```
product = M1(1,1,:,1) .* M2(:,1)

size(M1(1,1,:,1) -> 1 1 6
size(M2(:,1)) -> 6 1
```

If I use the command squeeze on M1 it is working.

```
product = squeeze(M1(1,1,:,1)) .* M2(:,1)
```

The problem is, squeeze takes extremely much time `(1/5 of the complete time -> ~50s)`. How can I still use my matrices without using squeeze? Anyone got an Idea?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using them in a loop? Show more of the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

[`shiftdim`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shiftdim.html) is usually faster, so try

```
product = shiftdim(M1(1,1,:,1),2) .* M2(:,1)
```